# remove row in array if value is NULL in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, nsarray

how to remove empty or Null value from Nsarray in objective c

here my sample code :

```
cell.subtitleLbl.text = [[chapterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"person"];
```

Comment: When you say "null" you mean `[NSNull null]`, right?

Comment: Please be more precise in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Choice-1**

```
// mainArray array is your current array
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [mainArray count]; i++) {
    id obj = [mainArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (![obj  isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { // or if (![obj  isKindOfClass:[[NSNull null]class]]) {
        [tempArray addObject:obj];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",tempArray);
```

**Choice-2**

```
[yourarrayName removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
```

**Choice-3**

ussing Predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS %@)", @"<null>"];
[yourarrayname filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

**Choice-4**

if you using array of dictionary

```
NSMutableArray *newarray=[NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in presentArrray)
{
    if (dictionary[key] != [NSNull null]) {
        [newarray addObject:dictionary];
    }
}
```

Comment: Choice-4 workers fine for my question Thank You

Answer (score 1):

use can Use Mutable Array

Remove null Objects from it

```
[arrayName removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
```